# Replace complicate text in a file using sed command

Tags: command-line, replace, sed, text-files

I have this text file 'foo.txt':

```
http:\\/\\/foo\\/dir\\/content\\/uploads\\
```

And I need replace

```
foo\\/dir
```

My text file 'foo.txt', I need look like this:

```
http:\\/\\/mysiteurl\\/content\\/uploads\\
```

I used *sed command*,

```
$ sed -i 's/foo\\/dir/mysiteurl/g' foo.txt
```

but show me errors, so: 
`'\\/'`.

Help Me plis!!

Answer (score 0):

This one will do the work:

```
sed -i "s|foo\\\\\\\\/dir|mysiteurl|g" foo.txt
```